# how to call a method from another dart file?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

in my programme i want to call the same path inside a methode called getPhoto()=>upload(statefulwidget) to other file or statefulwidget

```dart
Future getPhoto() async{

FirebaseFirestore fearbase = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

 Reference ref=FirebaseStorage.instance
 .ref()
 .child("${widget.user}/ProfileData")
 .child("Url_$postId");

 await ref.putFile(file!);
downloadUrl=await ref.getDownloadURL();

//  upload image to firestore
var list=[];
await fearbase.collection("users").doc(widget.user)
.collection("PostData").doc(ido)
.set({"PostUrl":downloadUrl,"ownerName":loggedInUser.username,"userId":loggedInUser.uid,"timestemp":postId,"PostId":ido,"like":FieldValue
.arrayUnion(list)})
.whenComplete(() => Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Image Uploaded successfully .i."));
// .then((DocumentReference ido) => ido.update({"PostId":ido.id}))

}
```

more specifically i want to get like field path from the other file

Comment: i want to get like Post function to that path

Answer (score 2):

You can use callback function to solve this.

```
Future<String> getPhoto() async {
  Reference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance
      .ref()
      .child("${widget.user}/ProfileData")
      .child("Url_$postId");
  await ref.putFile(file!);
  return await ref.getDownloadURL();
  //  upload image to firestore
  
  // .then((DocumentReference ido) => ido.update({"PostId":ido.id}))
}

Future upload(String downloadUrl) async {
  FirebaseFirestore firebase = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  var list = [];
  await firebase.collection("users").doc(widget.user)
      .collection("PostData").doc(ido)
      .set({
    "PostUrl": downloadUrl,
    "ownerName": loggedInUser.username,
    "userId": loggedInUser.uid,
    "timestemp": postId,
    "PostId": ido,
    "like": FieldValue
        .arrayUnion(list)
  })
      .whenComplete(() => Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Image Uploaded successfully .i."));
}
```

In usage, you can pass the function as follows

```
  getPhoto().then(upload);
```

Or

```
  final downloadUrl = await getPhoto();
  await upload(downloadUrl);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this.

But the simple one is you can create a class and define this method within the class.

```
class Demo {
    static void getPhoto() {
        print("photo");
    }
}
```

Then your can access it like

```
Demo.getPhoto()
```

Comment: how i can use the same path again . any idea?

Comment: If you create a separate file and define the above-mentioned class in that file, You can use it in any other file by just importing that file.